# How to create a pair from two or three keys in an object to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
alphabet_num = {
  "alphabet": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F"
  ],
  "numbers": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6"
  ],
  "roman": [
    "I",
    "II",
    "III",
    "IV",
    "V",
    "VI"
  ]
};
```

I want to convert this into a value pair array like this:

```
alphabet_num = [
                ["A","1","I"],
                ["B","2","II"],
                ["C","3","III"],
                ["D","4","IV"],
                ["E","5","V"],
                ["F","6","VI"]
               ]
```

I tried using the `Object.values` and `Object.entries` to figure this out but in vain.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Why not looping from 0 to 5 and creating `[alphabet_num.alphabet[i], alphabet_num.numbers[i], alphabet_num.roman[i]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let alphabet_num = {
  alphabet: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
  numbers: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
  roman: ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI"]
};

let finalArr = [];
alphabet_num.alphabet.map((eachElement, index) => {
  let arr = [];
  Object.keys(alphabet_num).map(item => arr.push(alphabet_num[item][index]) );
  finalArr.push(arr);
});

console.log(finalArr);  // [ ["A","1","I"], ["B","2","II"], ["C","3","III"], ["D","4","IV"], ["E","5","V"], ["F","6","VI"] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alphabet_num = {
  "alphabet": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F"
  ],
  "numbers": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6"
  ],
  "roman": [
    "I",
    "II",
    "III",
    "IV",
    "V",
    "VI"
  ]
};

var result = Object.keys(alphabet_num).map(function(key) {
  return alphabet_num[key];
});
var tempArr = new Array(result[0].length).fill("")
var final = tempArr.map((el, index) => [result[0][index],result[1][index],result[2][index]])

console.log(final);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `map` to achieve the task:

```js
var alphabet_num = { "alphabet": [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" ], "numbers": [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ], "roman": [ "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI" ]};

var result = alphabet_num.alphabet.map((k,i)=>[k,alphabet_num.numbers[i], alphabet_num.roman[i]]);

console.log(result);
```